# Do some Social Skills require more experience to level up than others?

Tags: persona-5

While trying to study right before my exams, I got a lot of Knowledge. However, I wasn't able to rank up to where I wanted to be in time, despite spending a lot more time studying than other activities that had already increased my other Social Skills, which seemed to have ranked up a lot faster. Does Knowledge take longer to level up than other stats? Do the stats all vary in how much experience is needed to increase them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are different thresholds for each Social Skill's level requirements. From [this page](http://www.ggez.space/parameters/), it is quite clear that Knowledge requires the most points to max, but Proficiency requires barely over half of that. It's worth noting, however, that Knowledge has by far the most opportunities to gain points, many from activities that don't even require you to spend an afternoon or evening.

The full breakdown of points required to increase each rank is as follows:

**Knowledge**

- Rank 2 (Learned): 20
- Rank 3 (Scholarly): 47
- Rank 4 (Encyclopedic): 72
- Rank 5 (Erudite): 105

**Guts**

- Rank 2 (Bold): 6
- Rank 3 (Staunch): 16
- Rank 4 (Dauntless): 31
- Rank 5 (Lionhearted): 64

**Proficiency**

- Rank 2 (Decent): 8
- Rank 3 (Skilled): 21
- Rank 4 (Masterful): 38
- Rank 5 (Transcendent): 55

**Kindness**

- Rank 2 (Considerate): 9
- Rank 3 (Empathetic): 28
- Rank 4 (Selfless): 56
- Rank 5 (Angelic): 82

**Charm**

- Rank 2 (Head-turning): 4
- Rank 3 (Suave): 32
- Rank 4 (Charismatic): 56
- Rank 5 (Debonair): 79